# What is the best way to abstract two slightly different functions in c++?

Tags: c++, templates

Let's say I have a class which implements any number of similar methods, same return type and same parameter type to keep it simple.

Header:

```
protected:
  void MoveForward(float Magnitude);
  void MoveRight(float Magnitude);
```

Implementation:

```
void MyCharacter::MoveForward(float Magnitude) {
  AddMovementInput(GetActorForwardVector() * Magnitude);
}

void Myharacter::MoveRight(float Magnitude) {
  AddMovementInput(GetActorRightVector() * Magnitude);
}
```

Very similar methods, but only differing by the direction (Forward and Right in this case) in the method name, and the name of one of the internal functions.

What is the best way to abstract the common generic structure here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it in multiple ways, personally I've used an approach similar to the following:

```
enum class Direction { LEFT, RIGHT, TOP, BOTTOM };

class MyCharacter {
   template<Direction DIR> Vector MyCharacter::getVector() const;

   template<Direction DIR> void move() {
     AddMovementInput(getVector<Dir>() * magnitude);
   }
}

template<> Vector MyCharacter::getVector<Direction::LEFT>() const { ... }
template<> Vector MyCharacter::getVector<Direction::RIGHT>() const { ... }
```

Of course you can do the same exact thing without templates but I guess that you know what you are doing if you are specifically needing them.

Mind that you could directly pass the function as a template argument but I found it less clear, something like:

```
float GetActorForwardVector() { return 3.0f; }

class Foo
{
public:
  template<float (*F)()> float move() { return F(); }
  inline float moveLeft() { return move<GetActorForwardVector>(); }
};

int main()
{
  Foo foo;
  std::cout << foo.moveLeft();
}
```

Comment: Maybe template wasn't the best word-choice. I mentioned in a comment to Ali above that I've broken out the repeated code into a macro which does the trick. The example above is just a simple example of something I find myself doing a lot (sometimes the bodies are larger) and was wondering about available language features that could help mitigate the repetitiveness.

Comment: The point is that templates in C++ are like blueprints, they're not a common type which handles many different template arguments but rather a different type for each template argument, having 4 directions will emit 4 different functions in the final binary, this can led to code bloating so it's not always what you want to do, so it depends.

Comment: Your latest edition seems to be close what I need. I'll give that one a try. Thanks :)

Comment: Re: your last comment. Yeah this is really just a simplified use-case to make the question less confusing. I'll keep that in mind though.

Comment: Yes and still you could obtain the same thing without templates, eg   `float move(float (*F)()) { return F(); } float moveLeft() { return move(&GetActorForwardVector); }`. The difference here is that you are passing the function at runtime as an argument instead that creating different versions of `move` for each function.

Comment: That's very handy.  Had no idea you could do that with function pointers.

Comment: I come to C++ after long working with javascript, so seeing the functional approach here is cool.

Answer (score 2):

To be honest you should not generalize at this level of algorithm. You just get a vector and scale it with a constant. If you were doing something more complex, then it would be another story. My first and foremost suggestion is let it stay this way.

Second, if you insist on generalization here it is (I assume GetXVector methods are class member):

```
class Foo
{
protected: 
    void MoveForward(float x) { Move(&Foo::GetActorForwardVector, x); }
    void MoveRight(float x) { Move(&Foo::GetActorRightVector, x); }
private:
    template<typename GetDirectionFunc>
    void Move(GetDirectionFunc getDirection, float x)
    {
        AddMovementInput((this->*getDirection)() * x);
    }
};
```

I prefer your original code.

Comment: I intentionally kept the example very simple. More or less just trying to understand what language features are available.

Answer (score 1):

You could use tag-dispatching.

Create the tag classes with same `static` member functions which implement the *specific* behavior:

```
namespace Direction {
struct Forward
{
    static Vector actorVector() { return GetActorForwardVector(); }
};

struct Right
{
    static Vector actorVector() { return GetActorRightVector(); }
};
} // namespace Direction
```

In your class, implement a template `move` function which takes an instance of the Direction class, but doesn't use it. Instead it calls the `static` member function of the tag class.

```
class MyCharacter
{
public:

    template< typename Direction >
    void move( const float magnitude, const Direction )
    {
        AddMovementInput( Direction::actorVector() * magnitude );
    }
};
```

Usage example:

```
MyCharacter mc;

mc.move( 10.0, Direction::Forward() );
```

If you want to create more directions, only a new tag class is needed which implements the static member function.

Comment: This is a nice pattern.  Is there a similar solution if the static Direction functions needed to access "this" (this being the MyCharacter instance) without passing it in at runtime?

Comment: That starts to get complicated. There is no way a class can access the variables of another class without having some way to access an instance.

Answer (score 0):

Templates are not meant to be used when you handle different values (forward, right), they meant to handle different types (int, double).
You can use one generic Move function with arguments:

```
void Move(int x, int y);

// Move forward
Move (0, 1);

// Move right
Move (1, 0);
```

You can use function pointers to combine move direction and corresponding function in a struct:

```
struct MOVE_INFO
{
    int x;
    int y;
    void (*GetVector)(void);
}

void Move(MOVE_INFO mv)
{
    ...
    mv.GetVector();
    ...
}

main()
{
    MOVE_INFO forward = {0, 1, SomeLib::GetForwardVector};
    MOVE_INFO right = {1, 0, SomeLib::GetRightVector};

    // Move Forward
    Move(forward);

    // Move Right
    Move(right);
}
```

Comment: That's not really an option, the "GetActorRightVector()" etc is part of unreal engine (to give you some context). I've already accomplished the goal using macros MY_MOVE(Forward), MY_MOVE(Right) respectively that obviously just dumb-copy the functions during preprocessing. There must be some better way to compose functions.

Comment: Templates can be properly used also to handle different values, not only types.